# Android studio is giving an output error 2 on start-up

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

I followed all the instructions to install Android studio 5.2 on my ubuntu. I am following the basic tutorial on a "hello world" application https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
. On startup I get an error message stating:

Error:Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I suspect that it has to do with java not properly communicating with the program, but I dont know where to start or how to fix this.

Are there any trouble shooting steps I can follow?

Thanks!!

Comment: could you put your gradle build  file  ?

Comment: This is not really relevant but Android's own tutorial is pretty bad IIRC. You perhaps are better off finding some other tutorial. Try Udacity/Coursera.